# How to use a class as user control property?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm somewhat new to c# so apologies if I have any of the terminology wrong

I have a user control and want to pass in a "Buffer" class I created on the properties window of the editor. I got the "Buffer" property to appear in the editor but it is greyed out and I can't edit it.

As an example I also added a new string property called "MyText" which I can edit in the editor.

Is it possible to use classes for a property?

[image]

Here's the code.

```
public partial class BufferControl : UserControl
{
    Buffer buffer = null; 
    string caption = ""; 

    [
        Description("Buffer to use for reads and writes"),
        Category("Appearance")
    ]
    public Buffer Buffer
    {
        get { return buffer; }
        set
        {
            buffer = value;
        }
    }


    [
        Description("Text for control"),
        Category("Appearance")
    ]
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return caption; }
        set
        {
            caption = value;
        }
    }

    public BufferControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the Properties Types of your Buffer class (bad name, change it asap) are all known Types (e.g., string, double, enumerators), then just decorate the class with `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]`. You also need to assign a new Buffer object in the UserControl's Constuctor. Since this is a *breaking change*, you need to remove the UC from the Parent Form, rebuild the Project and drop a new UC on the Form. If the Buffer class instead has a complex structure, you need a custom `UITypeEditor`. The editor can be a Form that provides Type editing and conversions (eventually).

Comment: Highly unlikely that a "buffer for reads and writes" should be a user-editable property.  Apply the [Browsable(false)] attribute.

Comment: Add `Browsable(true)`, and check if property has `set` method (not readonly property)